# How to make model for heavy api response json flutter

Tags: json, flutter, model, mapping

I am actually facing a problem trying to make a model for a json api response.
The response is really big and I have not found a way of making only a model for a part of it.

JSON scheme of api response : https://easyupload.io/0bo5gn

I tried converter like https://app.quicktype.io/. But none worked properly for a response of this size.

EDIT : How can I make a model and methods to get the whole refID list from the api response ? here is my model : https://easyupload.io/jxca3o

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [this](https://javiercbk.github.io/json_to_dart/) json to dart converter

[image]

Comment: A lot of errors generated by the converter on this model, I'll try to fix them and come back.
https://i.postimg.cc/wMSGZFpq/errors.png

Comment: can you share the api response

Comment: https://easyupload.io/0bo5gn you got a scheme here, is that good enough ?

Comment: I easily convert json to dart without any error... just copy your json and paste it on JSON section and some class name and generate it

Comment: Yes, I did it, I tried the scheme and even the json himself (worth ~170k lines).
The best model I got after fixing errors is with the scheme : https://i.postimg.cc/DzfPdzpf/error.png / https://i.postimg.cc/htZf6PPt/error-Description.png and as your see I think I got a problem with this. Because It might be interpreted as variables ?
https://i.postimg.cc/xdjBJnKM/type-In-Response.png > An example of the response API for this problem. I guess Flutter just cannot handle this ?

Comment: Corrected those errors, how do I access data ? (here is the model : https://easyupload.io/jxca3o)

Comment: Check this here i upload a file where i call random API you just have to change API parameter and URI...https://drive.google.com/file/d/13os2Gi-88SQrXszwnAq1L_9Z5ENQa7BK/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Thank you a lot, adjusted it to work with future builder but it's fine now!